# How might I match a string in ruby without using regular expressions?

Tags: ruby

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
(in initialize)
 @all = Stuff.all.each.map {|t| t.reference_date }
 @uniques = @all.uniq



results = []
@uniques.each do |k|
  i = 0
  @all.each do |x|
    i += 1 if x =~ %r{#{x}}
  end
  results << [k, i]
end
```

And that's fine. It's going to work. But I like to avoid regular expressions when I can. I think they are a bit feo. That's spanish for ugly.

EDIT--
actually, that's not working because ruby "puts" the date as a numbered format like `2012-03-31` when the date object is placed inside of a string (as a variable, here), but its really a date object, so this worked:

```
if x.month == k.month && x.day == k.day
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: why don't explain you us what trying to do with this?

Comment: I'm sharing my code pedro, isn't that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with just 1 line (if I got right the question of course):

```
array = %w(a b c d a b d f t z z w w)
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "d", "f", "t", "z", "z", "w", "w"]
array.uniq.map{|i|[i, array.count(i)]}
# => [["a", 2], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["d", 2], ["f", 1], ["t", 1], ["z", 2], ["w", 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
results = Hash.new(0)
@all.each{|t| results[t] += 1}
# stop here if a hash is good enough.
# if you want a nested array:
results = results.to_a
```

This is the standard way of getting the frequency of elements in an enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do to avoid the *appearance* of regular expressions, is to build them on the fly using `Regexp.union`. The reason you might want to do this is SPEED. A well constructed regex is faster than iterating over a list, especially a big one. And, by allowing your code to build the regex, you don't have to maintain some ugly (feo) thing.

For instance, here's something I do in different chunks of code:

```
words = %w[peer_address peer_port ssl ssl_protocol ssl_key_exchange ssl_cipher]
regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(words).source })\b/i
=> /\b(?:peer_address|peer_port|ssl|ssl_protocol|ssl_key_exchange|ssl_cipher)\b/i
```

That makes it trivial to maintain a regex. And, try a benchmark using that to find substrings in text against iterating and it'll impress you.

Answer (score 0):

If wildcards will work for you, try [`File.fnmatch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-fnmatch)

Answer (score 0):

From your code I sense you want to get the number of occurrence of each `reference_date`. This can be achieved much easier by using ActiveRecord and SQL directly instead of pulling the whole tale and then performing time consuming operations in Ruby.

If you are using Rails 2.x you can use something like this:

```
Stuff.find(:all, :select => "reference_date, COUNT(*)", :group => "reference_date")
```

or if you are using Rails 3 then you can simplify it to

```
Stuff.count(:group => "reference_date")
```